# USING SCOPE Everything not working

Tags: soql, contentdocument, files, contentdocumentlink

I wrote a trigger on ContentDocumentlink to get a count of number of files uploaded against Service_Request__c (Custom Object) record.It works fine for new files are uploaded on Service Request record.

But I want to get the count of number files already uploaded against Service_Request__c record .For that am running below code in developer console.

And am having difficulty in retrieving number of files using contentDocumentLink.

```
 list<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocumentLinkList = [SELECT id,linkedEntityId 
                        FROM ContentDocumentLink Using Scope Everything WHERE 
                         linkedEntityId IN :srIds];

 system.debug('contentDocumentLinkList Size'+contentDocumentLinkList.size());
```

returns only 350 records where as

```
list<ContentDocument> ContentDocumentList= [Select Id, Title,
                        FileExtension From ContentDocument USING SCOPE Team];

system.debug('ContentDocumentList size'+ContentDocumentList.size());
```

returns 4500 records.

All files in the org are related to Service_Request__c.I am not sure why query on ContentDocumentLink returns only 350.

If I try to update Query on ContentDocumentLink from Using Scope Everything to Using Scope Team then am getting

> Internal Salesforce.com Error

Using Scope Everything and Using Scope Mine  on ContentDocumentLink returns same number of records i.e 350.

Here is the code that am running in developer console.

```
Set<ID> srIds = new Set<ID>();

for(Service_Request__c sr : [select id,file_count__c from Service_Request__c] ) {
          sIds.add( sr.id );
}

map<id,Service_Request__c>srMap = new map<id,Service_Request__c>();

Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = Service_Request__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
String keyPrefix = r.getKeyPrefix();

srMap = new map<Id,Service_Request__c>([select Id,name,File_Count__c from Service_Request__c where Id in:srIds]);

list<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocumentLinkList = [SELECT id, linkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink Using Scope Everything WHERE linkedEntityId IN :srIds];

system.debug('contentDocumentLinkList Size'+contentDocumentLinkList.size());

for(ContentDocumentLink a: contentDocumentLinkList)
        {

               if((String.valueOf(a.LinkedEntityId)).startsWith(keyPrefix))
                {
                   Service_Request__c sr = new Service_Request__c();
                   sr = srMap.get(a.LinkedEntityId);
                   if(sr.File_Count__c >0){
                   sr.File_Count__c = sr.File_Count__c + 1;
                   }
                   else{
                     sr.File_Count__c = 1;  
                   }
                }
        }


update srMap.values();
```

**UPDATE:**

Is it because of access issue ?. When I clicked on the file sharing settings  against file then I see 'Any user of the Company' - 'No Access' and files are uploaded by Community Users.

Comment: What happens if you omit the [`USING SCOPE`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_using_scope.htm) from the ContentDocumentLink SOQL query? Have you tried examining one of the ContentDocument that isn't coming back in the first result of 350 records?

Comment: @DanielBallinger I tried removing USING SCOPE from ContentDocumentLink query and am getting same result i.e 350 records

Comment: How certain are you that there are more than 350 `ContentDocumentLink` records total in the org? How many records does the Storage Usage page under setup say there are?

Comment: I ran this query and got 4500 records .. select id,title from contentdocument using scope team

Comment: So there are 350 `Service_Request___c` records and a corresponding number of `ContentDocumentLink` records connecting them to `ContentDocument` records. Is the problem now that you don't know what the remaining 4,150 `ContentDocument` records are for?

Comment: Yes @DanielBallinger. I did random check and found that all files have link to Service_Request__c records.

Comment: I'd be looking closely at any of the `ContentDocument` records that aren't associated with the `Service_Request__c` record. What is in those records? Who created them? When were they created? etc...

Comment: Is it because of access issue ?. When I clicked on the file sharing settings then I see 'Any user of the Company' - 'No Access' and files are uploaded by Community Users.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Sorry my mistake I did checked file storage in sandbox. In production all files are related to Service_Request__c  and File Storage against Service_Request__c object is 4500 records.